# grid.arrange bins disappearing

Tags: r, ggplot2, grid

When I use grid.arrange the data in each of the plots disappears. I checked out a similar post from a while back but I couldn't find an applicable solution for my plots.

I have ten plots, each of which is a variation of this with a different variable:

```
ATN0_hist <- ggplot(data = c1dat0, aes(x = ATN0)) +
  geom_histogram(position="identity", alpha=0.5, fill="aliceblue", color="black", bins=10) + 
  labs(title = "Month 1", y = "Frequency", x = "% of Days Attended") +
  theme(panel.background = element_rect(fill="white"),
    axis.line = element_line(colour = "black", size = 0.25), 
    axis.ticks = element_line(colour = "black", size = 0.25),
    axis.text = element_text(color = "black", size = 10, family="Times"), 
    axis.title = element_text(size = 10, vjust = -.75, color = "black", family="Times"),
    plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5, vjust=+2, color = "black", size = 20, family="Times", face="bold"),
    plot.margin = unit(c(.125, .125, .125, .125), "in"),
    legend.position = "none")
```

Each individual plot is fine:

[image]

The problem, is when I try to use grid.arrange to align them all together in a grid:

```
grid.arrange(ATN0_hist, ATP0_hist, ATN1_hist, ATP1_hist, ATN2_hist, ATP2_hist, 
                        ATN3_hist, ATP3_hist, ATN4_hist, ATP4_hist, 
                        nrow=5)
```

Then I get this:

[image]

I would greatly appreciate if someone could tell me where I'm going wrong or if I should be using a different function altogether. I haven't done this in years.

Comment: Why not combine your data together, with a variable specifying the month, and just use `facet_wrap()` to create multiple plots?

Comment: This looks like a layout issue, since your plot titles and axis labels and axis titles are taking up all the vertical space at this resolution. Make them smaller and make your output taller and I bet the charts are all there, they're just squished to zero right now.